# Applying a scale and translate transformation to UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, affinetransform

I have a UIBezierPath and I would like to:

- Move to any coordinate on the UIView
- Make bigger or smaller

I am drawing the UIBezierPath based off of a list of predefined coordinates.  I implemented this code:

```
CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);

CGAffineTransform moveAndScale = CGAffineTransformScale(move, 1.0f, 1.0f);
[shape applyTransform:moveAndScale];
```

I have also tried scaling and then moving the shape, it seems to make little to no difference.

Using this code:

```
[shape moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

I start drawing the shape at (0, 0), but this is what happens.  I assume this is because a line is being drawn from 0, 0 to the next point in the list.

[image]

When I set the move transformation to (0, 0) this is where it draws.  Here, moveToPoint is set to the first coordinate pair in the list.  As you can see, it is not at 0, 0.

[image]

Finally, increasing the 1.0f moves the shape off the screen completely, no matter where the I tell the shape to move.

Can someone help me understand why the shape is not drawing at 0, 0 and why it moves off the screen when I scale it.

Comment: I might be wrong on this one, but doesn't this code (`CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);`) just say that something should be moved 0 pixels along the x-axis and 0 pixels along the y-axis? ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation)) It won't actually move anything to origo (0, 0), as it seems you are trying to do. Also, it seems like you are using `moveToPoint:` wrong as well..

Comment: You are right!  Taking that into account, I changed the numbers and it scales and I can see it now.  How am I using moveToPoint incorrectly though?  You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(As requested by the OP in a comment above)*

I might be wrong on this one, but doesn't this code

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
```

just say that something should be moved 0 pixels along the x-axis and 0 pixels along the y-axis? ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation)) It won't actually move anything to origo (0, 0), as it seems you are trying to do.

Also, it seems like you have slightly misunderstood how to properly use `moveToPoint:`.. Think of it as a way to move your cursor, but without actually drawing anything. It is just a way to say 'I want to start drawing at this point'. The drawing itself can be performed by other methods. If you wanted to e.g. draw a square with sides of length *L*, then you could do something like this..

```
// 'shape' is a UIBezierPath
NSInteger L = 100;
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(50, 50);
[shape moveToPoint:origin]; // Initial point to draw from
[shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(origin.x+L, origin.y)]; // Draw from origin to the right
[shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(origin.x+L, origin.y+L)]; // Draw a vertical line
[shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(origin.x, origin.y+L)]; // Draw bottom line
[shape addLineToPoint:origin]; // Draw vertical line back to origin
```

Note that this code is not tested at all, but it should give you the idea of how to use `moveToPoint:` and `addLineToPoint:`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful of the order you apply the transforms in and you should think about concatenating the transforms together and applying them in one go.

The order is important as each transform affects all x,y positions in the path. So, the translation is affected by the scale. Reverse the order and the path will be scaled and then moved.

Also, the coordinate system is important, particularly if you are scaling. Ensure you draw around 0,0 and then scale and then translate. This is easiest if you normalise the points. Normalising for lat/long values means dividing latitude by 90 and longitude by 180 (this will actually give you a range -1..1). When doing this you should first scale the path, then translate it to the centre of the view, then apply your desired translation.

Comment: please see the edits I made to the question.  They should clarify what I am asking.

Comment: What points are in the path and how are you adding them. The points should probably all be normalised between 0 and 1 so that you can scale and position the line sensibly.

Comment: They are actually longitude and latitude points that I convert into decimal then scale down to fit onto a UIView.  I add them by iterating through an array of points then adding them to the UIBezierPath like this: [shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)]; How do I normalize a point?

Comment: @Wain, How do you translate it to the center of the view after applying the scaling using `CGAffineTransform`s?